# UK Visitor visa: Can parents depart country of origin a day before the validity date?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, tourist-visas

My mum and dad applied for a UK standard visitor visa (tourism) and received the approval today. They have been given a multiple-entry visa for 6 months.

Their entry clearance vignette shows a validity date from 29/03/2024 until 29/09/2024.

I plan to book their flight tickets as follows:

Departure from the Philippines:
28/03/2024 at 19:50 (GMT +8 Manila time).

Arrival in the UK:
29/03/2024 at 06:40 (GMT London time).

Return to the Philippines: 28/04/2024.

I found that travelling on these dates would save some money vs the week after (and it coincides with Easter weekend, so I have time off to pick them up from the airport and spend time with my parents).

Does the *valid from* date as stated on the entry clearance mean the earliest permitted date of arrival in the UK? In which case I presume this would not pose a problem. However, I wanted to hear your thought on this and if you would advise differently.

Many thanks for your time!

Kind regards,
Carlo

PS. This forum has been extemely helpful in preparing for my parents' tourist visa application. I could not be more grateful for this community! Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your parents can leave the Philippines whenever they want as far as UK immigration is concerned. UK authorities can of course check their plane tickets and see that they come directly from the Philippines, but in general they also have to allow for more complicated itineraries where there visitors have been in some third country leading up to the visit, so they really don't care - as long as they don't try to enter the UK before they are allowed to.

Comment: Thank you very much, appreciate your thoughts on this.

Comment: While the UK immigration may not be concerned about the itinerary, the air companies (usually) want to make sure the passengers do not arrive to their destination before their visa allows them to. In the case of OP it should be fine anyways, since the arrival is on the 29th.